# Output several regression tables into multiple pages of a Word document in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer, sjplot

My goal is to create a multi-page Microsoft Word document with many formatted regression table outputs on consecutive pages. Ideally this would be done using R Markdown.

I have had some luck making nicely formatted regression tables in word using `sjPlot::tab_model`

So for example, I can do

```
mod2 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Species + Petal.Width, data=iris) 
sjPlot::tab_model(mod2, file = "~/Desktop/model2.doc")
```

to create a nice-looking regression table in a new Word document.

If I do

```
mod3 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Species + Petal.Width, data=iris) 
sjPlot::tab_model(mod2, file = "~/Desktop/model3.doc")
```

I can make a second Word document with another nicely formatted regression table.

The goal here is to create a single Word document containing both model outputs on consecutive pages.

I know that in R Markdown, I can make multi-page regression tables using Stargazer and Knit, e.g.,

`stargazer(mod2)`

But these only render in PDF or HTML.

I know that sjPlot doesn't directly knit to Word, so that's not an option.

Possible solutions include:

1. Using a different package to render Word-compatible regression output tables in Markdown
2. Finding a clever way to combine the `tab_model` outputs into a single Word document.
3. Some other way I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Have you tried Flextable? https://community.rstudio.com/t/nice-tables-when-knitting-to-word/3840/6

Comment: https://datascienceplus.com/how-to-export-regression-results-from-r-to-ms-word/

Comment: +1 on flextable. My workflow is to use `huxreg` from the `huxtable` package and convert to `flextable` with `huxtable::as_flextable()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The best way is to stick with `sjPlot`, knit to HTML, then copy and paste from HTML to Word. The table renders nicely that way.

Thanks to Andrew Reece (andrew_reece) for this one.

Comment: I found that copy and pasting from HTML to word results in the columns not lining up correctly and the bars at the top of the table not being long enough etc. Did you find a way to preserve the formating?

Comment: Is there a neat way of automating this?